# Docker Enable Xdebug

Tags: php, linux, docker, dockerfile, xdebug

I have such Dockerfile for my php-container:

```
FROM my-image/debian

ARG PHP_VERSION

...
...

RUN \
    set -eux \
    \
    # INSTALL SURY SOURCES
    && buildDeps='apt-transport-https lsb-release wget' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests $buildDeps \
    && wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg \
    && echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ buster main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list \
    \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    \
    # INSTALL PHP PACKAGES
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests \
      php$PHP_VERSION \
      php$PHP_VERSION-cli \
      php$PHP_VERSION-fpm \
      php$PHP_VERSION-opcache \
      php$PHP_VERSION-redis \
      php$PHP_VERSION-apcu \
      php$PHP_VERSION-zip zip unzip \
      php$PHP_VERSION-curl \
      php$PHP_VERSION-gd \
      php$PHP_VERSION-intl \
      php$PHP_VERSION-mysql \
      php$PHP_VERSION-soap \
      php$PHP_VERSION-amqp \
      php$PHP_VERSION-bcmath \
      php$PHP_VERSION-socket \
      php$PHP_VERSION-dom \
      php$PHP_VERSION-mbstring \
      php-pear \
      php$PHP_VERSION-dev \
    && mkdir -p /var/run/ \
    \
    # Install xdebug
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    \
    # CLEAN
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false $buildDeps \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* \
....
....
....
```

when I build it, i get error
**/bin/sh: 1: docker-php-ext-enable: not found**

I don't want to get image from alpine or other external php image. Cause particular reasons, i want to build php and have an hand from my-image/debian.

Could someone help me activate xdebug? It is well installed (via the pecl) but when I do `php -v` it is not there, even after rebuild and restart of the containers

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Script `docker-php-ext-enable` by default does not exists in Debian images.
You need co copy it into your docker-image like in [official  7.3 buster image](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/a310c86d0bc7e1be238aca04c8357d76b9c40ef6/7.3/buster/apache/Dockerfile#L263). Add to your `Dockerfile` string:

```
....
COPY docker-php-ext-enable /usr/local/bin/
....
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
....
```

Don't forget to place [docker-php-ext-enable](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/a310c86d0bc7e1be238aca04c8357d76b9c40ef6/7.3/buster/apache/docker-php-ext-enable) file into build-context dir.

Comment: after adding this file and copying it; I had a lot of small errors like permissions, missing libraries etc ... Finally I came across a comment saying that you just need to install php-xdebug, gcc, autoconf, libc-dev, ... .and boom by magic, it worked. In any case, thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

...Dockerfile
#Install Xdebug

`RUN PECL INSTALL xdebug \`

`&& docker-php-ext-enable xdebug`

`RUN chown notroot:notroot \`

`/<path in docker container for dockerphp--ext-xdebug.ini`

...docker-compose.yml

```
`volumes:
    - ./<path to local docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini>:/<path to docker docker-php-xdebug.ini`
```

Prerequisites:  You nned to have pecl installed previousy (higher in the Dockerfile)